# Execute command with correctly escaped paths

Tags: java, launching-application

See [this superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/512261/explorer-programmatically-select-file-directory-with-space-in-the-path) question. I need to run the command

```
explorer.exe /select,"C:\Program Files\foobar"
```

from Java. The following Java code does NOT work like the above command line call (the Explorer selects a completely different directory):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
    "explorer.exe",
    "/select,\"C:\\Program Files\\foobar\""
});
```

What other options I have from pure Java side (no native code)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could place the `/select` in a separate `String` token to stop it being treated as part of the path:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
        "explorer.exe",
        "/select,", 
        "\"C:\\Program Files\\foobar\""
        });
```

Comment: Thank you! It even works without the surrounding quotes in the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try ProcessBuilder. That API allows you to pass in arguments without quoting.
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#command(java.util.List)

Comment: The `exec(String[])` doesn't require quoting either.  In fact *none* of the `exec` methods of either `System` or `ProcessBuilder` *understand* quoting.